# What is the shiur Hanaah?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, issur-vheter, hanaah-benefit

How much Hanaah (physical benefit) must one have of things prohibited as an Issur Hanaah (things forbidden for benefit) like milk and meat, Kiley HaKerem (certain grape mixtures), or Avoda Zara (idolatry), to be punished for such Hanaah?

Answer (score 1):

**Meat & Milk - Kiley HaKerem**

It's not clear that there is a punishment (by Bet Din) for Hanaah.

See the Aruch HaShulchan ([Yore Deah 85:36-37](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9106&st=&pgnum=401)):

He says that the according to the Rambam (בס׳ המצות לאוין קפ״ז) there's only a punishment (lashes) for eating meat & milk, or Kiley HaKerem.

> **לו**: וטעמו מה שאין באיסורי הנאה מלקות ביאר בס׳ המצות לאוין קפ״ז  ‏

He continues (in 85:37): Other Rishonim - including the Ramban, ש׳׳ג (no idea who that is), Tosafos and Sma"g -  disagree:

> הרמב"ן ז״ל כתב מפורש דלוקין על הנאת בשר בחלב [שם בשורש ב'] ויש מראשונים דם״ל דלוקין על כל איסורי הנאה [ש׳׳ג גשם ריא״ז פ"ב דפסחים] וכן משמע מרבותינו בעלי ה תוס ׳ [חולין ק״ב. ד״ה אלא] וכן משמע מדברי הסמ״ג לאוין רנ״ט‏

But I have yet to find them mentioning a size.

**Avoda Zara**: Even the smallest amount.

> הלכות עבודת כוכבים וחקותיהם - פרק שביעי
>
> **טו:**  בָּשָׂר אוֹ יַיִן אוֹ פֵּרוֹת שֶׁהֱכִינוּם לְהַקְרִיבָם לַעֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים לֹא נֶאֶסְרוּ בַּהֲנָאָה אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהִכְנִיסוּם לְבֵית עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים עַד שֶׁיַּקְרִיבוּם לְפָנֶיהָ. הִקְרִיבוּם לְפָנֶיהָ נַעֲשׂוּ תִּקְרֹבֶת וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁחָזְרוּ וְהוֹצִיאוּם הֲרֵי אֵלּוּ אֲסוּרִין לְעוֹלָם. וְכָל **הַנִּמְצָא בְּבֵית עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים אֲפִלּוּ מַיִם וּמֶלַח אָסוּר בַּהֲנָאָה מִן הַתּוֹרָה. וְהָאוֹכֵל מִמֶּנּוּ כָּל שֶׁהוּא לוֹקֶה** : ‏

Bonus: **Ir haNidachas**: Even the smallest amount.

> [הלכות עבודת כוכבים וחקותיהם - פרק רביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01997.html#HtmpReportNum0027_L2)
>
> ז נִכְסֵי הַצַּדִּיקִים שֶׁבְּתוֹכָהּ וְהֵם שְׁאָר יוֹשְׁבֵי הָעִיר שֶׁלֹּא הֻדְּחוּ עִם רֻבָּהּ נִשְׂרָפִין בִּכְלַל שְׁלָלָהּ הוֹאִיל וְיָשְׁבוּ שָׁם מָמוֹנָן אָבַד. וְכָל **הַנֶּהֱנֶה מִמֶּנָּה בְּכָל שֶׁהוּא לוֹקֶה** אַחַת שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים יג-יח) 'וְלֹא יִדְבַּק בְּיָדְךָ מְאוּמָה מִן הַחֵרֶם':  ‏

Bonus: **Me'ila** - items consecrated to the Bet HaMikdash - a Peruta.

> [הלכות מעילה - פרק ראשון](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02001.html#HtmpReportNum0008_L4)
>
> **א:** אָסוּר לְהֶדְיוֹט לֵהָנוֹת מִקָּדְשֵׁי הַשֵּׁם. בֵּין מִדְּבָרִים הַקְּרֵבִין עַל גַּבֵּי הַמִּזְבֵּחַ. בֵּין מִקָּדְשֵׁי בֶּדֶק הַבַּיִת. וְכָל **הַנֶּהֱנֶה בִּשְׁוֵה פְּרוּטָה מִקָּדְשֵׁי הַשֵּׁם מָעַל**: ‏

Bonus: **Chometz on Pessach**: Even the smallest amount.

Rav Akiva Eiger explicitly says so in  תשובות עקיבא איגר ([Teshuva 19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24714&hilite=ed99d1b4-b9a7-49f9-b731-c36034d310c8&st=%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%94&pgnum=29)).

> ומה דהחמירו בחמץ דאוסר  במשהו מסתברא דזהו רק לעניין אכילה והנאה

Comment: there may be a problem of chazi shiur also: פתחי תשובה יורה דעה סימן פז ס"ק ב

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang - the question was "to be punished" - which I assumed to mean by Bet Din. As a general rule חצי שיעור אסור and it's fair to assume that upstairs you'll get into trouble for it. (Purposely being vague here.)

Comment: the first two are about eating

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - unsure what you're trying to say: "the first two are about eating "

Comment: *וְהָאוֹכֵל* כְּזַיִת מִכִּלְאֵי הַכֶּרֶם

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - haven't given up yet. I've been asking every Rabbi I have bumped into - and none seem to know the answer, much less "prove" their gut feeling.